# How to modify the the table's name in SQL in iBatis with Java code?

Tags: sql, ibatis

In **iBatis**, the requirement is that when I execute **SQL**, I need to add the prefix to table names.

For example: I need to execute **SQL**：`“ select * from student”`. But, actually, in the DB the real table name is `pms.student`. We don't want to add the `"pms"` in every **SQL**, so we need to add the prefix: `"pms"` to table names.

How I can do this in Java?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: cant you use `parameterClass="java.lang.String"` and use it in the query like `select * from $value$`

Comment: There's so many tables,if I do like this,it would be very redundant.Could I configure or do any other things, I can just do it foe once?

Comment: i don't think it is possible, But keep searching.